# How do I now the generic wrapped value on a Property Change Listener on Java Fx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I've got this code:

```
circle2.radiusProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            System.out.println("Change detected for " + observable);
            circle1.setRadius(newValue.doubleValue());
        }
    });

 final IntegerProperty lapCounterProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
  pathTransition.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {

        }
    });
```

How do I know what should be the type parameter for `ChangeListener<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addListener` method comes from [`ObservableValue<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html), which defines

```
void addListener(ChangeListener<? super T> listener)
```

while [`ChangeListener<S>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) defines:

```
void changed(ObservableValue<? extends S> observable, S oldValue, S newValue)
```

Keeping it simple (there usually isn't a reason not to), if you have a `ObjectProperty<Duration>` (which is what `PathTransition#duration`) is, you would want to use a `ChangeListener<Duration>`, which will have `changed` method with the signature:

```
void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue)
```

But you could also use a `ChangeListener<T>` for any `T` which is a supertype of `Duration` (`Object`, for example), while the `changed` method of the listener can accept an `ObservableValue<T>` for any `T` which extends Duration.

So the short answer is - if you have no good reason not to, always use the same type parameter of your `ObservableValue` for it's `ChangeListener`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you say/ask. The signature of `addListener` calls for `ChangeListener<? super T>`  (Read - a change listener of something that is a super-type of T), so if `T` is `Duration`, I can use a `ChangeListener<Duration>` or `ChangeListener<Object>`, as `Object is a super-type of `Duration` ( that is - `Duration` extends `Object`).

Comment: Well this is totally correct. I thought you mean the opposite way of a extending Duration class. Maybe my english is not good enough or it's a bit ambiguous to me.

Comment: I have edited the answer and changed it to "for any T which is a supertype of Duration", I hope this is clearer.